# what is the difference between Conventional 1D or 2D in keras layers

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I'm discovering `keras` library and i can't tell what does the dimention mean in `keras layer`s and how to choose them ? `(model.add(Convolution2D(...))` or `model.add(Convolution1D(...)) )`.

For example i have a set of 9000 train traces and 1000 of test traces and each trace has 1000 samples, so i created the arrays X_train with a size of 9000*1000, X_test has a size of 1000*1000, Y_train has a size of 9000, and Y_test has a size of 1000.

my question is how can i choose the first layer dimension ?.

I tried using the same example implemented in MNIST such :

```
model.add(Convolution2D(9000, (1, 1), activation='relu', input_shape(1,9000000,1),dim_ordering='th'))
```

but it didn't work, i don't even know what should i put in each argument of Convolution function.

Comment: In what way it "didnt work"? Got any errors?

Comment: The error occurs when executing model.add(Flatten()), it says :
Input 0 is incompatible with layer flatten_7: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2

Comment: @HajjiSofien I'd get rid of the Flatten() layer. That should keep your model at three dimensions since Flatten() will flatten it to two dimensions. (It might generate a different error after that related to your input/output shapes, but the current error should be solved.)

Answer (score 1):

The choice of dimension (1D, 2D, etc.) depends on the dimensions of your input. For example, since you're using the MNIST dataset, you would use 2D layers since your input is an image with height and width (two dimensions). Alternatively, if you were using text data, you might use a 1D layer because sentences are linear lists of words (one dimension).

I would suggest looking at Francois Chollet's example of a convolutional neural net with MNIST: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py. (Note: Conv2D is the same as Convolution2D.)

Comment: OK i understand, but could you tell me what is the meaning of each argument in the Convolution2D function when using MNIST dataset?.
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(1,28,28)))
What does 32 and (1,1) stands for ?

Comment: @HajjiSofien Check out the [Keras docs for Conv2D](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#conv2d).  The arguments are in order unless you specify them explicitly (like activation=.... or input_shape=....). Therefore, the first argument is the number of filters, while the second is kernel size, etc.